# 500 error on any new created php files

Tags: php

I'm getting a 500 internal server error on any new php files that I create on my server.

So even if they are blank or have something simple such as

```
<?php
echo "foo";
?>
```

They will still error.

I have created and successfully received .html files and am still able to get all my old php files, I just can't get any more that I create.

Why would it do this, is there some sort of limit on how many php files I can have on my server?

Comment: Check the file permissions on the newly created php files, they should be readable by the user running the webserver.

Comment: are you able to check server logs? 500 generally means something bad happened on the server.

Comment: edit one of your old php files to see if you get any error.

Comment: Is is for a local webserver or a hosted server?

Comment: Editing doesn't cause the error and its hosted.

Comment: @Shannon The reason I ask this is because I have free hosted sites on Netfirms and if I didn't pay for it to begin with, they disable PHP. When I try to run any PHP file on it, I get a 500 error.

Comment: @Fred I'm still able to run other php files though, I've also created quite a few but now any more simply 500 error.

Comment: @Shannon That is bizarre, never heard the likes of it. Don't know what else to tell you. Hopefully someone else will have some answers for you.

Comment: @muratgu Where would I find server logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP files should have execute permissions. If your OS is Linux

```
sudo chmod 777 foo.php
```

Comment: Isn't execution `755`?